# Adding button (shortcode) to advertisment area on wordpress

Tags: button, shortcode

I want to add the button (Shortcodes Ultimate) to the ad area on my theme options (ad management).

The button shortcode:

[su_button url="link" style="soft" background="#000000" color="#FFFFFF" size="6" wide="yes" center="no" radius="auto" icon="icon:sign-in" icon_color="#FFFFFF" text_shadow="none" desc="" onclick="" rel="" title="" class=""]text[/su_button]

It does not show the button, just the code. How I can make it that the button will show like on posts?

Comment: Please format your code correctly and add a tag to the language you're using.

Comment: What you mean? I added this code (of course I replaced "text" and "link" areas) on my post and it showed up correctly.